# How i can get/edit field from grid (adminhtml)

Tags: javascript, magento

Say me please, how i can get/edit filed from adminhtml grid. jQuery don't get value this field. event - click on row. i try edit "grid.js".

```
alert(jQuery("table#productGrid_table tbody>tr>td:nth-child(3)").html)
```

don't get result

if

```
alert(jQuery(this).html)
```

result is

```
function(a){ifa===b}return this[0]&&this[0].nodeType===1?this[0].innerHTML.replace....
```

idealy i wont use that script, on simple table it's work

```
jQuery("table#productGrid_table tbody>tr>td:nth-child(3)").on('click', function(){
    jQuery(this).parent('tr').find('input:checkbox').attr("checked","checked");
    jQuery(this).html("<input type='text' value='"+jQuery(this).text()+"' class='filterInput' autofocus/>");
    }).on('click', 'td input', function(){
        return false;
    }).on('focusout', 'td input', function(){
        jQuery(this).parent('td').text(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

someone help me please, thx

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i try edit product_name from adminhtml grid (click on field, rename)

Answer (score 0):

You're not invoking the html function - add parentheses to do that:

```
// alerts html content from selected node
alert(jQuery("table#productGrid_table tbody>tr>td:nth-child(3)").html())
//                                                                   ^^
```